# How to store data in a windows shared folder JSON without allowing users to read the data?

Tags: javascript, json, security, encryption, architecture

I've a local webpage that needs to store some usage metrics, current solution is a JSON file shared across users updated via javascript.

The problem with this solution is that users could also read the file. Is there any easy way of implmeenting a write-only JSON file in a shared windows folder? any alternative I could use?

Comment: Does the file have to be stored locally? If you instead write to a server, then you can control read access.

Comment: Yeah, my main limitation at my company is that I can’t have a server (for now) - I also need to keep everything in the intranet :(

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more what you mean by _local webpage_? Are the files served from a local web server or do users open them directly from the filesystem in the browser?
Also how is the JSON getting stored to the filesystem - especially when not using a web server? Do you want to limit the raw access to that JSON only for the users themselves or should also the webpage only be able to access parts of the data depending on which user is using it?